# How to create count down timer script 30mins for Acrobat?

Tags: countdown, acrobat

Can someone show me the count down script for Acrobat? 
(e.g. 30mins from the document opened, cos I'd attached a auto close script in the PDF).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**This will set up a timer for javascript in Acrobat**

```
if(CurrentTimer)
   app.clearInterval(CurrentTimer);
var CurrentTimer = null;
var timerHits = 0;

function TimeIsUp()
{
console.println("Timer Hit " + timerHits++);
}

CurrentTimer = app.setInterval("TimeIsUp();",1000)
```